# How to add compiler include paths and linker library paths for newly installed Boost?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, build, rpm

I have RHEL 5.2, with Boost 1.33 installed.
I downloaded boost_1_44_0.tar.bz2. and built it. On completion it showed:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home/dfe/Archive/boost_1_44_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home/dfe/Archive/boost_1_44_0/stage/lib
```

1. How do I add the above mentioned include paths?
2. When I do "rpm -q boost", it shows boost-1.33.1-10.el5. Why is that so, when I've installed version 1.44?
3. Is there a better way to install the latest version of Boost?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, I removed the existing boost rpm using

```
rpm -e boost-1.33.1-10.el5
```

A message is displayed saying "error: "boost" specifies multiple packages"

Then tried:

```
rpm -e --allmatches boost
```

(I don't remember whether I typed 'boost' or 'boost-1.33.1-10.el5')

The packages with dependencies were shown.
I did:

```
rpm -e [packagename1]
rpm -e [packagename2]
```

and so on and then did:

```
rpm -e --allmatches
```

This erased boost completely from my system.

Then I extracted boost_1_44_0.tar.bz2 using tar -xvjf boost_1_44_0.tar.bz2 and ran bootstrap with:

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

Then ran bjam as:

```
./bjam install
```

That's it! Boost got installed on my system, and I didn't have to specify any of the linker options while compiling programs! Yay!
Now the 'rpm -q boost' command shows that there is no package installed.

Comment: The key thing here is ./bjam install, because the instructions make it seem like ./b2 is the command to use to install.

Comment: On the use of `./b2` vs `./bjam`: http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/faq/names.html

Answer (score 25):

There are always three steps to install software on Linux systems:

1. configure — "check"
2. make — "build software in current directory"
3. make install — "copy files to the systems so the other software can use this software"

You likely did the equivalent of `make` but did not do the equivalent of `make install`. You need to run

```
sudo ./b2 install
```

after running `./b2`

Comment: This was helpful on my Debian8.

Answer (score 15):

Just add the paths to your .bashrc or .profile (or whatever floats your boat) like this:

```
export LIBS="-L/home/dfe/Archive/boost_1_44_0/stage/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/dfe/Archive/boost_1_44_0"
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted … can someone explain what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 11):

You have to include these directories into makefile which you would use to build your application

```
CC -I/home/dfe/Archive/boost_1_44_0 -L/home/dfe/Archive/boost_1_44_0/stage/lib yourprogram.cpp
```

-I option Adds dir to the list of directories that are searched for #include files.

-L option adds dir to the list of directories searched for libraries by linker

CC is sun compiler...

Comment: Yay! It worked! Thanks! Although my intention was to have the old version of Boost completely replaced by the new version. Right now, the files in /usr/include/boost/ seem to have got updated, but it's annoying to keep linking to the /home/dfe/Archive/boost_1_44_0 folder in every program that I use. Anything I can do to make 1_44_0 the default version?