# How do I integrate C++ Boost into a Qt project?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, boost

I would like to use boost/filesystem.hpp in my Qt app but the builder keeps saying:

```
Library not loaded: libboost_filesystem.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

here is how I try to link it:

```
INCLUDEPATH+= /installdir/boost_1_50_0  
LIBS += -L/installdir/boost_1_50_0/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem
```

I've tried linking directly, too. I've also tried rebuilding boost according to [jschoen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435067/adding-boost-library-to-a-c-project-in-os-x-eclipse), no difference.
Im running a MacOSX Lion. How do I have to link boost properly?

Comment: Thanks, I did use my full path indeed, no difference, but I'll tidy up this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meantime I have found a solution.

1. install boost with macports (sudo port install boost) Thanks to [dies and Tim Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos).
2. then link against:

`INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include`
`LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib`
`LIBS += -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt`

Comment: how do you 'link against' in Qt Creator?  This looks like makefile code I need to be modifying somewhere.  Is done through the GUI?  Can you provide more explicit direction?

Comment: nm, macports seems to have gone irrelevant.  searching for other options.

Comment: you are a lifesaver!  Been beating my head against insane compile times and missing includes when trying to bring boost into QtCreator.  Thanks!