# How to include the boost library into a C++ program?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction, include

I am trying to compile this small program:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/poisson.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace math {

template <class RealType = double, 
          class Policy   = policies::policy<> >
class poisson_distribution;

typedef poisson_distribution<> poisson;

template <class RealType, class Policy>
class poisson_distribution
{ 
public:
  typedef RealType value_type;
  typedef Policy   policy_type;

  poisson_distribution(RealType mean = 1); // Constructor.
  RealType mean()const; // Accessor.
}

}} // namespaces boost::math
```

This code is taken from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/poisson_dist.html).

The compiler tells me that `boost/math/distributions/poisson.hpp` is not found. So, I try to find this file by myself (using `locate poisson.hpp` command). I find the following file: `/opt/software/boost/1.45_ubuntu12.4lts_gcc4.5.3/include/boost/math/distributions/poisson.hpp`. So, in my code I put the full name of the file to make sure that compiler finds it:

```
#include </opt/software/boost/1.45_ubuntu12.4lts_gcc4.5.3/include/boost/math/distributions/poisson.hpp>
```

But now I get another error message: `boost/math/distributions/fwd.hpp` is not found.

Is there a way to force the compiler to search the files in the correct directory?

I use `g++` compiler.

Comment: The canonical guide for build systems expectation seems extremely broad, even for a blog post. That seems best suited for Documentation.

Comment: Moreover, it seems better suited for *multiple* people to answer, since people don't generally switch build systems like clothes, and one person is unlikely to have completely up-to-date information and experience (a good answer would mention common pitfalls, after all...) on more than four different build systems. Another point for the Documentation, I suppose. Does uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC want other compilers as well? Visual Studio has its own "common build system" but also doesn't use g++. If there turns out to be one answer for each build system (post limit considerations), who gets the reputation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need an include path in your g++ command:

```
g++ -I/opt/software/boost/1.45_ubuntu12.4lts_gcc4.5.3/include/  [rest of command here]
```

(and possibly a link to a library path as well).

In general, it's *not* a good idea to put full paths in your source code; that kind of completely destroys the idea of portability :) (meaning, that code can no longer be compiled on any other PC in the world than your own, and even *that* is going to be dubious half a year from now).

Anyway, if you find yourself typing long compiler lines like the one above, it's really time to start using a [makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)).

You'll probably find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123618/how-to-add-compiler-include-paths-and-linker-library-paths-for-newly-installed-b) interesting as well.

Answer (score 7):

(This isn't a direct answer to the question, but a list of considerations that I think should be addressed with the final and complete answer that @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC wants to see here.)

The question of handling 3rd party dependencies with C++ isn't a simple one. There are many approaches for this and choosing the approach that is right for you depends on your toolset and environment, on your project management and on the trade-offs you want to take.

For Boost, we have to remember that it's mostly header-only library, but some components include a separately-compiled part too (can be static or dynamic lib, can be mandatory for the component or just for a specific use-case of it).
E.g. Boost.Filesystem requires compilation, Boost.Graph requires it only if you want to parse GraphViz files and Boost.Variant doesn't need it at all (is "header-only" library).
For details, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries (this redirects to the latest version, which is currently 1.61).

Using only header-only parts of Boost simplifies many of the considerations, but, of course, sometimes you need the other parts too.

Things to consider:

1. Are you using only header-only parts of Boost or you need a
   separately-compiled part too? If you need a separately-compiled
   part, do you use static lib or dynamic lib? If you use
   separately-compiled part and want to use dynamic lib, you have to
   decide how to find the dynamic lib when running the application
   (especially if you distribute your project as binary).
2. Is your project distributed as source or as binary? In the binary
   case, you worry mainly about the developer workflow (but see the
   point above about using dynamic lib). In the source case, you want
   it to be easy to compile on every other computer.
3. Do you want your project to stick with the same version of Boost (at
   least until you explicitly decide to change version) or you want it
   to use whatever is installed on the specific machine (assuming there
   is no API changes)?
4. Are you OK with having a copy of Boost (or part of it) with the
   project or you want a central location for all your projects to use?
5. How much manual config steps you want to force on the users (end
   users or developers, depends on the other questions above)? (0 is
   probably preferred, but there is always a trade-off.)
6. Is your project Windows-only, Linux-only, etc.? Each platform has
   its own ways and depending on your answer to other questions, the
   methods you should use can vary between OSes.
   Cross-platform, for our topic, usually means that you have to
   implement the relevant approaches for each of the platforms you want
   to support.
7. What is your toolset and build environment (e.g. Visual Studio, Qt,
   make, simple scripts, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

To specify a directory to search for include files:

```
-I /opt/software/boost/1.45_ubuntu12.4lts_gcc4.5.3/include
```

To specify a directory to search for libraries:

```
-L /opt/software/boost/1.45_ubuntu12.4lts_gcc4.5.3/lib
```

To specify the actual library name:

```
-l foo
```

> when your library is called lib**foo**.a

you don't have to write space after `-I`, `-L` or `-l` for now it is more readable.

**HINT:**

Use Makefile. Maybe you have the boost include patch already exported to some environment variable.

Comment: Some editors only support CMake. Does not qualify for bounty as of now.

Comment: i don't want the bouny :)

Comment: I was wondering if i post under a question with 160k view if my `people reached` will increase.

Comment: I believe the requirement is that you need a highly upvoted answer on a question for the question's views to count towards your own *people reached* count. Of course, the question then is *what constitutes a highly upvoted answer?*