# boost "too old" for ardour and wouldn't install

Tags: c++, linux, boost, path

I am trying to install **ardour 3.0** on my ubuntu 14.04.
I've downloaded the source from their site.

but when I run `./waf configure` it writes

```
Checking for boost library >= 1.39                   : too old
Please install boost version 1.39 or higher. 
The configuration failed
```

and aborts.
after some searching I've found [this site](http://wiki.tiker.net/BoostInstallationHowto) that explaines how to install boost on unix systems. I've followed the next instructions:

> **Step 1: Install Boost**
>
> You may install via your operating system's package manager or from
>   source.
>
> **From Source**
>
> These instructions will help you install the Boost C++ libraries on a
>   Unix-like system. If you already have them installed, make sure that
>   it's the version required by the software you would like to use. If
>   not, no problem, we'll build it now.
>
> On Linux, make sure you have the Python headers (i.e. development
>   information) installed. Your operating system may call this package
>   something like python-dev or python-devel.
>
> Next, download the boost release tar.bz2 file. To untar the file, use
>   tar xfj boost_1_39_0.tar.bz2.
>
> On OS X, you may have to modify a couple of files to build
>   Boost.Python properly. See
>   https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3930.
>
> Then, do this from the boost download directory:

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$HOME/pool --libdir=$HOME/pool/lib --with-libraries=signals,thread,python  
$ ./bjam variant=release link=shared install
```

> On recent versions, the second line should read

```
./b2 
./b2 install
```

after executing ./b2 terminal showed me :

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home2/tor/Downloads/boost_1_55_0 (2)

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home2/tor/Downloads/boost_1_55_0 (2)/stage/lib
```

I don't know how to add **compiler include path** nor **linker library path**.
 after a quick search I have found a question about this exactly: 
**[How to add compiler include paths and linker library paths for newly installed Boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123618/how-to-add-compiler-include-paths-and-linker-library-paths-for-newly-installed-b)**

Only when I do "rpm -q boost" it shows "package boost is not installed".

the answer says "That's it! Boost got installed on my system, and I didn't have to specify any of the linker options while compiling programs! Yay! Now the 'rpm -q boost' command shows that there is no package installed."

but when I run

> ./waf configure

on the ardour folder again, it shiws me the exact same message.

what do I do to make the system recognize boost?
is the problem with Ardour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of installing Boost manually have you tried installing it using your distro's package manager?

```
 sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

As far as I know you should get the version you want, even on lucid (10.04 LTS).

Comment: Please install boost version 1.56 or higher....ok I will...
 sudo apt install libboost-all-dev ...
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.74.0.3ubuntu7)

Comment: Update: "sudo apt install g++" and Ardour is now compiling! It seems to need two different C++ compilers?